# A and ~A in logical proof

Tags: logic, proof

In my logic class last semester, we went over proofs with the rules of induction and replacement. In a couple of the exercises, I noticed something. In each of the exercises in question, all of the letters in the conclusion weren't in any of the premises. So how I went about getting to conclusion is that I eventually got to some letter by itself (like A) and the opposite (~A). I then added the entire conclusion to the A through addition and used the ~A to prove it using a disjunctive syllogism.

My question is that if I am able to have both A and ~A in the same proof, wouldn't that mean that the argument is invalid because there is a contradiction?

Here is an example of one of the problems that I came across and my proof for it (which it said was correct):

[image]

Comment: As per @Nick R's answer, the premises of the argument are contradictory, i.e. they are not (jointly) *satisfiable*. Consider 3rd premise: **~O**; it is *true* when **O** is *false*. Then consider 2nd premise: **W v O**; if **O** is *false*, in order for it to be *true* we must have **W** *true*. Thus: **O** is *false* and **W** *true*. Finally, consider 1st premise, i.e. the conjunct **W ⊃ O**: with **W** *true* and **O** *false* it is *false*. Thus, it is impossible that all three premises are simultaneously *true*.

Comment: In conclusion: no wonder that in the derivation you can find a *contradiction* : **O** and **~O**. It was already there from the beginning...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you may be confusing the notions of validity and soundness.

A valid argument can certainly derive a contradiction.  For example, a (valid) *reductio ad absurdum* argument, sometimes called proof by contradiction, is a valid argument that derives a contradiction.

The example you give is a valid argument.  However, the fact that it allows you to derive a contradiction means that it is not sound.  The conclusion one can draw is that at least one of the premises must be false.

See the [IEP article on validity and soundness](http://www.iep.utm.edu/val-snd/) for more details.  See also [this article](http://www.iep.utm.edu/reductio/) on the *reductio ad absurdum* method.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, when premises contradict, any conclusion (even a false one) is true. This is due to the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) (*ex falso quodlibet*):

> The principle of explosion ... is the law of classical logic, intuitionistic logic and similar logical systems, according to which any statement can be proven from a contradiction.

We can rewrite several premises P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub> as one: P = P<sub>1</sub> ∧ .. ∧ P<sub>n</sub>. If the premises contradict each other, this conjunction will be false.

Therefore, for any Q the implication P → Q will be true. Hence, any conclusion Q follows from P. This is due to the truth table of implication, where a false antecedent always give a true outcome.

In proof methods, we abstract from the actual content of premises and conclusions. The principle of explosion is applicable whenever a premise is false. So, also from the premise "France has a king" we can derive anything, even though it does not have the form A ∧ ¬A. Therefore, the fact that the premise contains both A and ¬A is insignificant with respect to the proof method and therefore with respect to the validity of the argument.